# Applescript autoclick returns -1700 error

Tags: macos, safari, click, applescript

I want to make applescript autoclick for me in a special spot on the Safari tab, i have tryed this one:

```
    delay 10
    tell application "System Events"
        tell application process "Safari"
            click (click at {650, 730})
        end tell
    end tell
```

but it's returning error:
click application process "Safari" at {650, 730}
        --> error number -1700 from {650, 730} to list

What does it meen?

Comment: If you are looking to click items on a page, use Javascript. If you are looking to click menu items in Safari, use UI scripting.

Answer (score 1):

In Mavericks `click at` doesn't work as expected anymore. You can found some discussions via [google](https://www.google.com/search?q=applescript%20%22click%20at%22%20mavericks&oq=applescript%20%22click%20at%22%20mavericks).

You have to look for alternatives:

[Cliclick](http://www.bluem.net/en/mac/cliclick/) (free tiny shell application from Carsten Bluem)

[python](https://discussions.apple.com/message/25436093#25436093) (Tony T1 wrote a python solution in apple forum)

[MouseTools](http://www.hamsoftengineering.com/codeSharing/MouseTools/MouseTools.html) (another free command line tool from HAMSoft)

PS

Don't use `click` twice. It's just: `click at {650, 730}`

Comment: Can you expand on this answer a little? From the help section on answering questions: `Please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.`